# c# convert base class to derived and conversely

Tags: c#, inheritance

"Questions that may already have your answer" (This topic seems like it may have been discussed, but I am asking a slightly different question)

I have three classes.
`Main()` method calls only `new Processor()`

I am having trouble in the `foreach()` - this doesn't work properly. 
I think `Animals[X,Y] = new Cat();` too but i have not tested it - compiler called me bad guy;

```
public class Processor
{
    Animal[,] Animals;
    public Processor()
    {
    Animals = new Animal[10,10];
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int X = 0; X < 10; X++)
        for(int Y = 0; Y < 10; Y++)
            {
            if(rand.Next(4) == 1) 
                 Animals[X,Y] = new Cat();
            else Animals[X,Y] = new Dog();
            }

    foreach(Animal animal in Animals)
        {
        if(animal.IsCat)
            {
            Cat MyCat = animal;
            DoSome(MyCat);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoSome(Cat cat)
    {
    Never mind.
    }
}


public class Animal
{
    bool IsCat = false;
    public Animal(){}
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat()
    {
    IsCat = true;
    }
    string MyColor = "White";
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(){}
    string MyOwner = "Dave";
}
```

Comment: I've never gotten the "You're a bad guy" message from the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the issue with trying to use a `foreach` to loop through an array of arrays, you need to explicitly convert `animal` to a Cat, either through an explicit cast or by using the `as` operator:

```
if (animal.IsCat) 
{
    Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
    // alteratively: Cat cat = animal as Cat;
    DoSomethingFeline(cat);
}
```

For more details, [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The `Animals` is a two dimensional array. It is an array of arrays. An array of arrays doesn't implement the `IEnumerable` interface as `System.Array` type does. Hence you can't loop through it's items using a `foreach`.

As it is stated more formally in MSDN

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element **in an array** or **an object collection** that *implements* the
>   **System.Collections.IEnumerable** *or*
>   **System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable** interface. The foreach
>   statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the
>   information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items
>   from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you
>   need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for
>   loop.

Comment: I am really used not this code, this is similarly example. Please, look trouble i noticed

Comment: @cat I am sorry but I can't get you. Isn't this your code and isn't this your problem?

Comment: This is similary code i written analogically to code i have really (real project more complex). 
Problem in assigning Cat VariableName = animalVariable, where animalVariable are cat really.

Comment: @cat Ok. But how can we help you if you don't state clearly your problem. Two similar problematic cases may have different causes. Please try to post an exact analogy of your problem. Not the actual code, but an exact analogy and re-state again what's your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have `List<Animal>` that must be randomly filled with inherited classes from `Animal` class. Classes `Cat` and `Dog`. 
I need to process this `List`. To do it i must do something like

```
Foreach(Animal A in AnimalList)
{
if(CheckingThatItIsCat(A)) 
 {
 Cat C = A;
 }
}
```

I really know what this `A` are really `Cat` class but this code line calls a syntax error.